# how to create plotly histogram with two columns

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I have dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'_3321131460': ['col1', 'col1', 'col2'], '_3952604542': ['col1', 'col2', 'col2']})
df
```

So want to create graph like this
[image]

one graph but x are two columns and legent have two columns data

And y is count But know how to do that

So one columns histogram, another columns histogram in one graph

But have same legend

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your df with `melt` in order to have the column names in their own column:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px 

df = pd.DataFrame({'_3321131460': ['col1', 'col1', 'col2'], '_3952604542': ['col1', 'col2', 'col2']})
df_t = df.melt()
```

This will have the following form (feel free to rename the columns to get fitting labels on your final plot):

```
      variable value
0  _3321131460  col1
1  _3321131460  col1
2  _3321131460  col2
3  _3952604542  col1
4  _3952604542  col2
5  _3952604542  col2
```

Then use `px.bar`:

```
fig = px.bar(df_t, x='variable', color='value', barmode="group")
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhh!! i dont think solution melt